# Unable to Git clone but can do a Git pull/push on already cloned repo

Tags: git, clone

I have a remote Git repository from which i cloned and am able to pull/push to that repository. But recently when i tried to reclone the same repository to a different directory it is not working.

```
$ git clone -v 'http://user@server.com/git/project.git' project  
Initialized empty Git repository in f:/temp/project/.git/  
Password:  
error: cannot spawn git: No such file or directory
```

I can still do a git pull and push on the repository which i had already cloned.

I tried goggling for this error but not much of help. Can someone also tell me how i can debug such kind of errors?

Comment: By any chance was any more output after that?

Comment: What's `git remote -v` say for the repo you can still push/pull from?

Comment: @David No more output after that

Comment: @Raisen Yes git is in the path i can execute other git commands from the same command line

Comment: @Schwern origin  http://user@server.com/git/project.git (fetch)
origin  http://user@server.com/git/project.git (push)

Answer (score 1):

`git` is unable to start the required subcommand for fetching HTTP repositories. It's likely to be `/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-fetch` – if it's missing, reinstall Git.

---

If on Linux, use `strace` to verify which program `git` tries to execute.

```
strace -o /tmp/git.log git clone http://.../

grep "^exec" /tmp/git.log | grep "ENOENT"
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is a problem with local git installation. I get the same error when i try to clone it from some other machine which has a fresh git installation. And also i can clone other repositories in the same directory in remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, http isn't working.  It could be a problem with your git http server (if it's affecting multiple clients) or your git installation (if all those clients are using the same version of git).

Your existing repository is using ssh, that's what `git remote -v` told you.  So you can continue to use that.  `git clone user@server.com/git/project.git` should work.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you have too many tags on your repository
(in our case we had more than a thousand automatically created by Jenkins)

The question : is it neccessary to keep that many tags ?
if not delete some of them

Comment: Here is more information about the problem and how to reproduce it : http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Clone-fails-on-a-repo-with-too-many-heads-tags-td7383212.html